# Java EE plugin for Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.5.1. There is no option called web-->Dynamic web project. Should I install any plugin for [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition)? If so, please provide me the plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Help -> Install new software.
The Eclipse update site URL to use with the update manager is:

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/

Enter the above link and test the connection. It will update Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably find the 'getting started guides' [here](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/index.php?category=enterprise) helpful.

You probably will need to download the plug-in. The easiest way to do this would be to:

1. go to Help -> Install new software.
2. Pick the Galileo repository
3. All the way at the bottom there are install options for 'Web, XML, and JaveEE Development

... also this is better suited for SO

Comment: This is the correct answer. You need to install the EE and Java Web Tools Plugin. Also I would have expected this on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help > Install New Software... expand "Work with" input and select "Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo" or write the same text but changing "indigo" for your version of Eclipse. Then select "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development" (or something like that) and press "Next". That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but couldn't update the standard Java edition because it couldn't resolve dependencies. I downloaded Eclipse JEE which includes all of Java

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php